How to modify the body text of the cover page of a word document using python-docx?
The cover page has a different footer and header, along with text in the body. I have a placeholder in the cover page body <date> that I want to replace. However, there doesn't seem to be any way to access and/or modify the text on the cover page body.
The only available methods to access the cover page are:

document.sections[0].first_page_header
document.sections[0].first_page_footer

Trying either of these reference the "second" page, ignoring the cover page:
document.sections[0].header.paragraphs
document.paragraphs

I'm open to a different library if it allows modifying the cover page body text.
